# Question about dividing a line segment as a ratio.

Tags: geometry, ratio

[image]

Hi, I am unsure to how can I divide the diagonal BD of this parallelogram as BD:BF = 4:3, and I also can't seem to find a solution online. Does this mean that BF is 1:3 in BD? How would I draw this?

Thanks in advance.

Let A, B, C and D be consecutive points of a parallelogram. Point E divides the diagonal AC so that AE : EC = 1 : 3.Point F divides the diagonal BD so that BD : BF = 4 : 3. Let S be the point of intersection of line segments AF and ED.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{BD}{BF}=\frac43\\\frac{BF+FD}{BF}=\frac{3+1}3\\\implies\frac{FD}{BF}=\frac13$$

F divides BD in the ratio $3:1$